How do I validate input from a defined type in PostGreSQL in a function?
I'm used to using a MERGE statement in MS SQL (SQL SERVER) to validate input in a Stored Procedure/Function that matches a defined table type, but I'm finding it difficult to replicate that behavior in PGSQL.
For instance, let's say I have a table called "holiday" that has a SERIAL id, a VARCHAR name, a DATE date, and a VARCHAR region.
I have created a similar type called t_holiday which includes everything except the SERIAL id.
My intent is to create a function which accept any number of rows for the holiday table in the form of t_holiday, insert new rows (using DEFAULT for id), and either return a success message or RAISE EXCEPTION citing the rows that already exist (by date and region).
I have tried 2 different methods of approach and both have failed to actually insert. The first was  like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createHolidays (holidays t_holiday[])
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $func$
DECLARE bad_holidays t_holiday[];
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO holiday h
    USING holidays hs ON h.date = hs.date AND h.region = hs.region
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (hs.date, hs.name, hs.region)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO bad_holidays VALUES (hs.date, hs.name, hs.region)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM bad_holidays LIMIT 1) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID ENTRY: holiday(s) % exist already', bad_holidays;
    ELSE RETURN 'Holidays successfully inserted';
    END IF;
END $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM createHolidays(ARRAY[
    CAST(ROW('2024-01-01', 'New Year''s Day', 'US') AS t_holiday),
    CAST(ROW('2024-01-15', 'Martin Luther King Day', 'US') AS t_holiday),
    CAST(ROW('2024-02-19', 'Presidents Day', 'US') AS t_holiday),
    CAST(ROW('2024-05-27', 'Memorial Day', 'US') AS t_holiday)
]);

Which failed, saying the table holiday didn't exist in one instance and that bad_holidays didn't exist in the other (I forgot what I changed to get the message to change).
After a bit more research, I changed my approach slightly to this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createHolidays (holidays t_holiday[])
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $func$
DECLARE bad_holidays t_holiday[];
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT hs.* FROM holidays hs
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM holiday h WHERE h.date = hs.date AND h.region = hs.region)
    INTO bad_holidays;
    
    INSERT INTO holiday
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (date, region) * FROM holidays
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM bad_holidays LIMIT 1) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID ENTRY: holiday(s) % exist already', bad_holidays;
    ELSE RETURN 'Holidays successfully inserted';
    END IF; 
END $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM createHolidays(ARRAY[
    CAST(ROW('2024-01-01', 'New Year''s Day', 'US') AS t_holiday),
    CAST(ROW('2024-01-15', 'Martin Luther King Day', 'US') AS t_holiday),
    CAST(ROW('2024-02-19', 'Presidents Day', 'US') AS t_holiday),
    CAST(ROW('2024-05-27', 'Memorial Day', 'US') AS t_holiday)
]);

Which is complaining that holidays doesn't exist on the first line it is accessed.
EDIT per suggestion:
When I switch to UNNEST in the first example, it changes the MERGE statement to this:
    MERGE INTO holiday h
    USING UNNEST(holidays) hs ON h.date = hs.date AND h.region = hs.region
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (hs.date, hs.name, hs.region)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO bad_holidays VALUES (hs.date, hs.name, hs.region)

and then errors on the table holiday not existing, even though it does...
Alright, after applying UNNEST to the second scenario it almost completely works:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createHolidays (holidays t_holiday[])
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $func$
DECLARE bad_holidays t_holiday[];
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT hs.* FROM UNNEST(holidays) hs
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM holiday h WHERE h.date = hs.date AND h.region = hs.region)
    INTO bad_holidays;
    
    INSERT INTO holiday
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (date, region) * FROM UNNEST(holidays)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(bad_holidays)) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'INVALID ENTRY: holiday(s) % exist already', bad_holidays;
    ELSE RETURN 'Holidays successfully inserted';
    END IF; 
END $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM createHolidays(ARRAY[
    CAST(ROW('2024-01-02', 'US', 'Day After New Year''s Day') AS t_holiday), -- does not exist yet
    CAST(ROW('2024-01-15', 'US', 'Martin Luther King Day') AS t_holiday) -- exists
]);

The issue now is that it's complaining about the structure of the insert, but only when at least 1 of the rows already exists (it doesn't matter what order they appear in):
ERROR:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.malformed array literal: "2024-01-02" 

ERROR:  malformed array literal: "2024-01-02"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
Context: PL/pgSQL function createholidays(t_holiday[]) line 4 at SQL statement


Seems you have an identifier issue with your table names. Use psql to see how the tables are actually named. If they are are either mixed case or upper case they will need to be double quoted when used in query to preserve case. See Identifiers for mor einformation.

@AdrianKlaver I'm not sure what you mean. The only "mixed case" instance is the name of the function, which hasn't presented an issue in any of the previous 30+ functions I've written for this project. Maybe I'm missing something, though. Perhaps you could point it out? Maybe I've just been looking at this too long to see it...

Alright, I saw SELECT DISTINCT hs.* FROM holidays ... and assumed you where referring to a table. Then I looked at the function signature and saw that holidays is actually an array. The SELECT is not going to work like that. Probably related to the t-sql tag. This is Postgres/plpgsql t-sql syntax may not work. You will need to use an array function to pull from the array. I have not delved into the function deep enough to figure out which one at this point.

@AdrianKlaver I feel like your suggestion is to use SELECT DISTINCT hs.* FROM UNNEST(holidays) hs...
Does that seem right? I'm going to try it and see if I can get a better response.

holiday not existing could be one of two things: 1) The a fore mentioned identifier case issue. 2) Or a search_path issue. In psql do show search_path and see if the schema holiday is in the path. If it is not you either have to schema qualify the table name e.g. some_schema.holiday or add the schema to the search_path.

@AdrianKlaver That seems to have worked for the second situation. Can you post an answer to get more credit for it?
In the case of the first, I've cleansed the schemas from the function.

I am not sure what worked, fixing the case of the identifier or schema qualifying/search_path modification?

@AdrianKlaver The part about adding UNNEST to the function. I added more above.
